# Joining CSV file to Shp file using ogr2ogr and python?

Tags: shapefile, csv, ogr2ogr, attribute-joins

I am having problems with the code below i.e. parsing the SQL string in python. I keep getting an error. I am joining a CSV file called `lookup_scales.csv` to a shp file called `RC_CATALOGUE_GRANTED`. I am running the ogr2ogr command within python and using `os.system` to call it. It doesn't like the `'lookup_scales.csv'` part i.e the apostrophes around it. BTW I was able to run the command successfully within a DOS window so not sure why is fails in the `os.system` call?

Also the shp file and csv file actually sit in different directories and would like to specify those locations in the `ogr2ogr` command. At the moment to get the command to work in DOS I have had to put the shp file and csv file in the directory I am running the python code I have.

Code:

```
os.system('ogr2ogr -sql "select RC_CATALOGUE_GRANTED.*, lookup_scales.* from RC_CATALOGUE_GRANTED left join 'lookup_scales.csv'.lookup_scales on RC_CATALOGUE_GRANTED.SCALE = lookup_scales.Scale" shape_join.shp RC_CATALOGUE_GRANTED.shp')
```

Above based on the Join CSV file to shapefile thread on here

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your apostrophes (`'lookup_scales.csv'`) are simply unnecessary - I really didn't get why they are there: when realizing left join the syntax is `JOIN Table1_name (alias if need) ON Table1_name.field = Table2_name.field`

```
os.system('ogr2ogr -sql "select RC_CATALOGUE_GRANTED.*, lookup_scales.* from RC_CATALOGUE_GRANTED left join lookup_scales.csv lookup_scales on RC_CATALOGUE_GRANTED.SCALE = lookup_scales.Scale" shape_join.shp RC_CATALOGUE_GRANTED.shp')
```